# Display major links in Google

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I am wondering how some websites get their sublinks too displayed on Google. For example when I enter "accenture" on Google apart from the main link (which is common) look at the links "Graduate Careers at accenture", "Accenture careers" etc.

How can I display my other pages too on Google just like this way.

Also when somebody enters my business name how can I display my map on Google just like the below screenshot.

Check the screenshot here. Sorry I don't have reputation 10 to post image. :(
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZFkv.png